# Relative layout - stick buttons to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with two sub relative layouts:

The first sub layout contains two text views, the second sub relative layout is below the first sub relative layout. However when I design all looks fine. When rendered on phone the buttons don't align to the second sub relative layouts bottom. Here is my code:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relative_img" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="Mike Anderson"
                    android:textColor="#ea2634"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="02dp"
                    android:text="My New Home"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relative_txt1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relative_txt1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative_txt1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="04dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_share" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_email" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_call" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The buttons I want to stick to the bottom shift up and are aligned below the second text view if there is space. 
Any hints what I am missing?

This is my complete list view row code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativePrime"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relative_right" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/leftView"
            android:layout_width="05dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#560978" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_default"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relative_img" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="Mike Anderson"
                    android:textColor="#ea2634"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="02dp"
                    android:text="My New Home"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relative_txt1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relative_txt1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative_txt1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="04dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_share" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_email" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_call" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_pet_2x" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_left"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Desired:

[image]

Current status:

[image]

Comment: Remove `android:layout_below="@+id/relative_txt1"` from button relative layout and check. and show screenshot of what you get if possible.

Comment: Nah with that it sticks over the text views - The layout shifts up to overlap text

Comment: Sure I will update with the screen shot

Comment: And also, change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in main outer layout

Comment: android:layout_alignParentTop="true" add this to first sub relative layout. hpoe it works

Comment: @MSGadag Not working, thanks although :)

Comment: show your required layout. n welcome :)

Comment: I have updated the above, with screen shot of Desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this layout using `LinearLayout` and `FrameLayout`. You can try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/leftView"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#560978" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_default" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mike Anderson"
            android:textColor="#ea2634"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="02dp"
            android:text="My New Home"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_pet_2x" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_share" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_email" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_call" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- for right side's red portion -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @user2822178: if u want to change it `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` then u can try it and let me know if something goes wrong

Comment: Thanks buddy, please maintain the hierarchy. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. if it works for you change height according to your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativePrime"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relative_right" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/leftView"
            android:layout_width="05dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#560978" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relative_img" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_txt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="Mike Anderson"
                    android:textColor="#ea2634"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="02dp"
                    android:text="My New Home"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dateText"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateText" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="04dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_left"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Close, however I want to preserve the layout hierarchy, the text below the image should be center horizontal there are certain criteria. SO I would want a workaround to my original XML. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_txt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Mike Anderson"
                android:textColor="#ea2634"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="02dp"
                android:text="My New Home"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_email" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_call" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_share" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

**I have made some changes:**

1- In the parent tag of relative layout i have removed `android:layout_alignBottom`, `android:layout_alignTop`, `android:layout_toLeftOf`, and `android:layout_toRightOf` no need for them because you already set width and height `match_parent`.

2- In textView2 tag removed `android:layout_alignParentRight` because using it with `android:layout_alignParentLeft` can be replaced by setting width with `match_parent`

3- In textView3 changed `android:layout_alignLeft` to textView2 with `android:layout_alignRight` because doesn't make sense to align left for a view and align right to parent !!.

4- In button1 tag removed android:layout_alignTop tag because it refer to a view which is not in the same scope "the parent relative layout" so this line will not work.

Please make those changes and make screen shot for the result.