# Why dont the buttons stick to the bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

### [Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582524/relative-layout-stick-buttons-to-bottom/26582957?noredirect=1#comment41784023_26582957)

This is my layout, I want the buttons to stick to the bottom, I have tried everything that I know of, but them rebels them buttons they wont stick to the bottom:

Here is my XML:

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_txt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relative_img"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relative_img" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Mike Anderson"
                android:textColor="#ea2634"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="02dp"
                android:text="My New Home"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_email" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_call" />

            

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_share" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: above `layout` worked for me...where do you want to show it? Where do you find it right now?

Comment: Hi, if you are using relative layout, open Graphical Layout of your xml file and just drag the buttons to the bottom.

Comment: The above is working fine if you check it in Eclipse (Graphical Editor), gets distorted when it runs on a device, the buttons jump up just under the text views. Its driving me crazy!!

Comment: Also please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582524/relative-layout-stick-buttons-to-bottom)

Comment: Checked in device also ...it works..

Comment: can you make a draw with what you expect and what u have

Comment: Yes please check the Link at the start of the question named as "Background"

Comment: @dreamcoder Its not working in my case Please check the "Background" link

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_txt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_img"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relative_img"
                android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relative_img" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="Mike Anderson"
                    android:textColor="#ea2634"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="02dp"
                    android:text="My New Home"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_email" />

               <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="warp_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_img"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relative_img">



                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_call" />



                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_share" />
              </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not working bro, it gets shifted onto the Text views when run on a device

Answer (score 0):

Edited your XML file..Try this it will help you.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relative_txt"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_img"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relative_img"
android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relative_img" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Mike Anderson"
    android:textColor="#ea2634"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="02dp"
    android:text="My New Home"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageviewContactus"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_email" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_call" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_share" />
</RelativeLayout>
```